# Mysql select max maximum sum values

Tags: php, mysql, sum, max

I have a database which contains some picture data and a linking table. The tables are build-up like this:

```
---pictures---
picid    Lat  Lon
1        5    6
2        7    31
3        31   43
4        -3   35

---user2pictures---
picid   userid  vote
1       1      1
1       2      1
3       1     -1
3       2      1
4       2     -1
```

The table pictures contains a picture id and some data about the image, the table user2votes contains vote data from the images. Each user is able to vote on images, but they can only vote 1 time, so the vote will be either 1 (like) or -1 (dislike).

I want to select everything from the pictures table from pictures which have the highest number of votes. Pseudoquery which might explain better what I want:
`SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE (SELECT MAX(SUM(vote)) FROM user2pictures LIMIT 12`

In this example picture 1 would return at the top, picture 3 would follow and picture 4 as the last one. I really don't know how to solve this, some help in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to `JOIN` the tables, `SUM` the votes, and `ORDER` high-to-low by the sum of the votes

```
SELECT pictures.*, SUM(user2pictures.vote) AS VoteTotal
FROM pictures
JOIN user2pictures ON pictures.picid = user2pictures.picid
GROUP BY pictures.picid
ORDER BY VoteTotal DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
   select p.`picid`, `Lat`, `Lon` from pictures p
   inner join user2pictures u2p
   on p.picid = u2p.picid
   group by u2p.picid
   order by sum(vote) desc
   limit 12
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0996/3)

Comment: Thanks for your input! Also thanks for the demo, I didn't know such thing existed, very useful for testing.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you also want to show the pictures with no votes. So, you can try this:

```
select 
    p.picId, sum(v.vote) as votes
from 
    pictures as p
    left join user2pictures as v on p.picId = v.picId
group by
    p.picId
order by
    sum(v.vote) desc
limit 12;
```

The `left join` is what lets you show the pictures with no votes (the column `votes` will have the value `0`)

Hope this helps